# Regular expression to replace specific numbers to space

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot

Given:

```
a = 0145067168
b = 0245067167
c = 0345067166
d = 0445067165
e = 0545067184

z = 2545067168
```

How do I remove leading indicators **("01", "02", "03","04","05")**, using regular expression

This is the output I'm expecting:

```
45067168
45067167
45067166
45067165
45067184

2545067168
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: So you are looking to replace `^0[1-5]` with nothing??

Comment: yes but only if they are leading with ("01", "02", "03","04","05")

Comment: that's exactly what the regex of @JvdV matches! `^` matches the start of the string, `0` matches exactly one 0 and `[1-5]` matches exactly one character from 1 to 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So maybe you meant to use:

```
^0[1-5]
```

---

```
public class Test{
     public static void main(String []args){
        String[] elements = {"0145067168", "0245067167", "0345067166", "0445067165", "0545067184", "2545067168"};   
        for (String s: elements) {           
            //Do your stuff here
            System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^0[1-5]", "")); 
        }
     }
}
```

Displays:

```
45067168
45067167
45067166
45067165
45067184
2545067168
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replaceFirst()` method to remove the values `("01", "02", "03","04","05")`

> replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement) Replaces the first
> substring of this string that matches the given regular expression
> with the given replacement.

Try this:

```
String a = "0145067168";
String output = a.replaceFirst("01|02|03|04|05", "");
System.out.println(output);
```

Output:

```
45067168
```

Comment: i updated my post

Comment: @nickel updated my answer..

Answer (score 1):

Why use regex here? Regex are cpu intensive. Convert it to string and use substring

```
if (a.startsWith("0")) {//condition where u want it to be applied
 a = a.substring(2);
}
```